# Narrow ILM cooler choice

Tags: cooling

I'm waiting for delivery of a Supermicro X10SRi-F board, which takes a narrow ILM cooler. I don't yet have a cooler. I don't want to go for water-cooling for this board and there isn't server-style forced airflow, so it'll have to be an air cooler > 135 TDP.

I've found about 3 or 4 narrow ILM coolers around (Dynatron R14, Noctua D9DX/U9DX/U12DX, and Supermicro SNK-P0050AP4) but I can't see clearly how they physically fit and what their orientation would be on the board, so I'm stuck.

I'm trying to ensure (1) that the cooler has its airflow towards the back of the case (with a consumer-ATX style layout with sockets at the back), and (2) that I can use all 8 RAM slots without being limited to just brands with ultra-low profile modules.  I'd like it quiet-ish but I can always buy an aftermarket fan so that's not a huge limit, but I'd prefer to avoid the Dynatron for that reason.

From online photos of the board, it looks like there's about 86-88mm between the RAM slots closest to the cooler (not 100% sure but I think so). I might be able to squeeze another couple of mm by slight cooler modding at the edges, if nothing else is better. I definitely prefer a quiet machine but don't need it silent.

Which cooler should I buy?

Comment: I got some bad news for you, and that is that you're not gonna get satisfactory performance out of a quiet narrow cooler. I would get the fan that WORKS and build the case around it to quiet the noise.

Comment: Quiet doesn't always mean poor performance - there's a whole sector for quiet performance PC building/modding and they cover this. In the end  did solve this myself but it wasn't easy to find reliable answers

Comment: In my experience quiet pretty much does mean "poor" performance in one way or another. Let us know how that U12DX works out for you at ~140W.

Comment: For sure.  And In mine it means careful checking/stress testing and larger sink/fan (or multiple fans).